# How to update projects with composer support?

Tags: deployment, composer-php, githooks

I hope the question is somehow explaining, what I want to do. If not, I'll try to give a more detailed explanation:

I am currently migrating a big project from SVN to Git. In this project, all the depencencies where stored in different folders and where commited to the SVN repo. I already learned, that [you should not put the vendors folder in your repo](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md). But how would I than update the depenencies? In another ressource I read, that you should only versioning the `composer.lock` file. How about the `composer.json` file?

Here is the strategy, I had in mind:

- Excluding the vendor folder in the `.gitignore` file
- Adding `composer.json` and `composer.lock` file to the repo
- Adding a composer_update.php file to use it in a post-receive hook

When we have to update some dependencies, we have than to do the following:

- Updating the `composer.json` file
- Running `composer update` locally to update the `composer.lock` file (or the `composer_update.php` script in your local dev instance)
- Pushing the changes to Stash/Bitbuckt/Github, which will than execute the `composer_update.php` script through the post-receive hook

Would you recommend something like this, or is there a better way to do it? I am sorry, but I am really new to composer.

Comment: What is the `composer_update.php` script supposed to do? On Github???

Comment: The `composer_update.php` file would be used by the post-receive hook triggered by Stash/Bitbucket/Github abs will run something like `shell_exec( 'composer update' );` so that you don't need to SSH to the server and run the command manually. There is a `git_pull.php`script doing the similar thing for Git.

Comment: You don't have a shell on Github, I suppose. And also, the command is wrong. You don't want to update, you want to install. And you DON'T want to install on the server hosting your repository (why there), you want to install during deployment withing your deployment script. Git however is not a deployment tool.

Comment: I think you missunderstand "projects" in this context. It is not a projects that offers composer support, but one using composer to load the dependencies. It's only the code for this project laying on a Stash/Bitbucket/Github hosting. The project itself is deployed to a production webserver. I just want to know, how my developers can update the components in this running production website using composer.

Comment: I think I understood correctly. :) If you deploy, that is the perfect time to: 1. Grab the code from the Git repo. 2. Install dependencies (note that you may some day have other dependencies than PHP/Composer - just think about some Javascript dependencies) 3. Put the result onto the production server. You won't UPDATE the Composer dependencies because that will likely install a different version than the one you tested and QA'd with. And you won't want to update with a post-receive hook because that would only work on the location the repository is on - and that shouldn't be the prod server.

Comment: That let's say I want to update any dependency. In my `composer.json` file I update the version number and run `composer update` locally. Than I test everything and it's all fine. I commit and push the changes `composer.json` and `composer.lock` file to the repo. I update both to prod server. But how do I update the `vendor` folder? Manually? Using FTP? Probably not. Adding the `vendor` folder to the repo? Probably also not the best idea.

Comment: The only step that runs `composer update` is you doing it locally, then testing if everything still works as expected. By doing so, the lock file will get updated and point to the new dependencies. Comitting the files will make Composer be able to install these versions everywhere else by running `composer install`, getting a correct vendor folder with the new versions, the old versions being removed/deleted. Which deployment tool do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to commit both `composer.json` and `composer.lock`, as these two files are essential for Composer operation. I bet you misread on what not to commit - from all the things a run with Composer creates, you ONLY commit the lock file, and nothing else.

Comment: OK, so both files, just as I thought. And how abaout the updating process (with the post-receive hook)?

Comment: You don't update stuff unattended, you would only install. See my comment on your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Commit both the `composer.json` and `composer.lock` file.
2. To update dependencies while development just run `composer update` in a terminal.
3. To update dependencies on production run `composer install` in a terminal. You may add this command to the post-receive hook.